# WOW.js - how to avoid data-* attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, wow.js

I'm using [WOW.js](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/docs.html) to animate a few `div` containers and would like to avoid the `data-*` attributes.

**Example HTML**

```
 <div class="wow slideInLeft" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="5s">Content</div>
```

**Example JS**

```
var wow = new WOW({
    boxClass:     'wow',      
    animateClass: 'animated', 
    offset:       0,          
    mobile:       true,       
    live:         true        
});

wow.init();
```

Is it possible to **control the data attributes** *duration, delay, offset* and *iteration* by a class or by JS, e.g. on init()?

My workaround would be to search for classes like `class="wowDelay-5s"` and add an attribute to it's element as `data-wow-delay="5s"`, but I prefer the proper way, if there is any.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the proper way to use WOW.js is with data-* attributes - why are they a problem?

Comment: The CMS I've to work with only provides a field to set the `class`-attribute. I can't directly manipulate the HTML element and it's attributes.

Comment: ahhh, then, yes, you could do it the way you suggest

Comment: You'd need to "pre-process" the tags before calling `wow.init()` I would suggest

Comment: Please tell me, did you find a solution?

Comment: @ВалерийЕмельянов Sorry, but I can't remember. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are 2 different ways to get the data attributes with jquery.

fisrt, you look for the attr

```
var firstWay = $('.wow.slideInLeft').attr('data-wow-duration');
```

second one is to use the data function from jquery

```
var secondWay = $('.wow.slideInLeft').data('wow-duration');
```

to set the attribute with an init function it simple too

```
$('.wow.slideInLeft').attr('data-wow-duration') = '2s';
```

and

```
$('.wow.slideInLeft').data('wow-duration', '2s');
```

i hope this helps you

Comment: I think you need to read the question again - he wants to use class like `wowDuration-5s` - and "convert" that to attribute `data-wow-duration: 5s` - because he can't directly create the data-* attributes in his CMS